# How to open a json file with Intake?

Tags: intake

I'm trying to use `intake` to create a data catalogue for a JSON file.  [#197](https://github.com/intake/intake/issues/197) mentions "Essentially, you need to provide the reader function `json.loads`, if each of your files is a single JSON block which evaluates to a list of objects."

I created a `test.json`

```
{
    "test": "test"
}
```

and (copying [Data Engineering with Intake](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)) tried

```py
import json
import intake
source = intake.open_textfiles("test.json", decoder=json.loads)
print(source.yaml())
```

saved the output to `source.yaml`

```
sources:
  textfiles:
    args:
      decoder: !!python/name:json.loads ''
      urlpath: test.json
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.textfiles.TextFilesSource
    metadata: {}
```

and tried opening it

```py
cat = intake.open_catalog('source.yaml')
```

which produced:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConstructorError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-9b8e3a51ebc2> in <module>()
----> 1 cat = intake.open_catalog('source.yaml')

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/__init__.py in open_catalog(uri, **kwargs)
    160         raise ValueError('Unknown catalog driver (%s), supply one of: %s'
    161                          % (driver, list(sorted(registry))))
--> 162     return registry[driver](uri, **kwargs)
    163 
    164 

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/local.py in __init__(self, path, autoreload, **kwargs)
    550         self.autoreload = autoreload  # set this to False if don't want reloads
    551         self.filesystem = kwargs.pop('fs', None)
--> 552         super(YAMLFileCatalog, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    553 
    554     def _load(self, reload=False):

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/base.py in __init__(self, name, description, metadata, auth, ttl, getenv, getshell, persist_mode, storage_options, *args)
    111         self.updated = time.time()
    112         self._entries = self._make_entries_container()
--> 113         self.force_reload()
    114 
    115     @classmethod

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/base.py in force_reload(self)
    168     def force_reload(self):
    169         """Imperative reload data now"""
--> 170         self._load()
    171         self.updated = time.time()
    172 

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/local.py in _load(self, reload)
    580                 logger.warning("Use of '!template' deprecated - fixing")
    581                 text = text.replace('!template ', '')
--> 582             self.parse(text)
    583 
    584     def add(self, source, name=None, path=None, storage_options=None):

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/local.py in parse(self, text)
    649         """
    650         self.text = text
--> 651         data = yaml_load(self.text)
    652 
    653         if data is None:

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/utils.py in yaml_load(stream)
     73     """Parse YAML in a context where duplicate keys raise exception"""
     74     with no_duplicate_yaml():
---> 75         return yaml.safe_load(stream)
     76 
     77 

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py in safe_load(stream)
    160     to be safe for untrusted input.
    161     """
--> 162     return load(stream, SafeLoader)
    163 
    164 def safe_load_all(stream):

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py in load(stream, Loader)
    112     loader = Loader(stream)
    113     try:
--> 114         return loader.get_single_data()
    115     finally:
    116         loader.dispose()

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in get_single_data(self)
     49         node = self.get_single_node()
     50         if node is not None:
---> 51             return self.construct_document(node)
     52         return None
     53 

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_document(self, node)
     53 
     54     def construct_document(self, node):
---> 55         data = self.construct_object(node)
     56         while self.state_generators:
     57             state_generators = self.state_generators

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_object(self, node, deep)
     98                     constructor = self.__class__.construct_mapping
     99         if tag_suffix is None:
--> 100             data = constructor(self, node)
    101         else:
    102             data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/utils.py in no_duplicates_constructor(loader, node, deep)
     30     for key_node, value_node in node.value:
     31         key = loader.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
---> 32         value = loader.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
     33         if key in mapping:
     34             from intake.catalog.exceptions import DuplicateKeyError

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_object(self, node, deep)
     98                     constructor = self.__class__.construct_mapping
     99         if tag_suffix is None:
--> 100             data = constructor(self, node)
    101         else:
    102             data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/utils.py in no_duplicates_constructor(loader, node, deep)
     30     for key_node, value_node in node.value:
     31         key = loader.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
---> 32         value = loader.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
     33         if key in mapping:
     34             from intake.catalog.exceptions import DuplicateKeyError

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_object(self, node, deep)
     98                     constructor = self.__class__.construct_mapping
     99         if tag_suffix is None:
--> 100             data = constructor(self, node)
    101         else:
    102             data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/utils.py in no_duplicates_constructor(loader, node, deep)
     30     for key_node, value_node in node.value:
     31         key = loader.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
---> 32         value = loader.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
     33         if key in mapping:
     34             from intake.catalog.exceptions import DuplicateKeyError

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_object(self, node, deep)
     98                     constructor = self.__class__.construct_mapping
     99         if tag_suffix is None:
--> 100             data = constructor(self, node)
    101         else:
    102             data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/utils.py in no_duplicates_constructor(loader, node, deep)
     30     for key_node, value_node in node.value:
     31         key = loader.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
---> 32         value = loader.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
     33         if key in mapping:
     34             from intake.catalog.exceptions import DuplicateKeyError

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_object(self, node, deep)
     98                     constructor = self.__class__.construct_mapping
     99         if tag_suffix is None:
--> 100             data = constructor(self, node)
    101         else:
    102             data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)

/home/wsl-rowanm/miniconda3/envs/ireland-smartmeterdata/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py in construct_undefined(self, node)
    427         raise ConstructorError(None, None,
    428                 "could not determine a constructor for the tag %r" % node.tag,
--> 429                 node.start_mark)
    430 
    431 SafeConstructor.add_constructor(

ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/name:json.loads'
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 16:
          decoder: !!python/name:json.loads ''
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this and would really appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that example is out of date. The reason is, that we decided that YAML files should be loaded via the safe mode, so that contained references to python objects are not executed. This means that you can always load an unknown catalogue and examine it, before deciding if you want to access any of its contents and possibly executing code.

As things stand, your workaround would be to get the data into memory and then decode it by hand, e.g.,

```
cat = intake.open_catalog('source.yaml')
cat.textfiles.to_dask.map(json.loads). # via dask
[json.loads(obj) for obj in cat.textfiles.read()]  # straight python
```

You could lodge an issue with Intake suggesting that one should be able to define a post-load processing step in textfiles using the fully-qualified name of the function ("json.loads" in this case) instead of a function object.

Also, we are planning to introduce a "derived datasource" in Intake which will more generally apply a function-and-arguments to any other data source, and that could be used for your case too - but it's not yet implemented.